# Output video segments via a pipe using FFmpeg

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

My Node.js app uses FFmpeg to capture video of a DirectShow device and then output segments for live streaming (HLS). At the moment I'm outputting the segments to files, however if I could output them via a pipe it would allow me to efficiently send the segment via a websocket instead of hosting a HTTP server.

I've tried using this command:

> ffmpeg -y -f dshow -i video=FFsource:audio=Stereo Mix (Realtek High
>   Definition Audio) -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -threads 0 -b:v
>   3300k -cpu-used 5 -keyint_min 150 -g 150 -map 0 -flags:v
>   +global_header -f segment -

However it gives the error "Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Muxer not found". This commands works for outputting to files (by replacing '-' with 'seg_%03d.webm').

Does FFmpeg not support pipes for segmented video, or is there something wrong with the command? Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean to output segmented files on a pipe?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Use `-f nut` instead of `-f segment`. The `nut` format could contain all types of headers and audio, video codecs.

```
ffmpeg -y -f dshow -i video=FFsource:audio=Stereo Mix (Realtek High Definition Audio) -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -threads 0 -b:v 3300k -cpu-used 5 -keyint_min 150 -g 150 -map 0 -flags:v +global_header -f nut pipe:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `ffmpeg -i pipe:0 pipe:1` to read from stdin and output to stdout.

You can take a look at an example FFmpeg wrapper I use in one of my projects:

https://github.com/lperrin/node_airtunes/blob/master/examples/play_ffmpeg.js

If you plan on streaming from the network, you might need a circular buffer at some point. There's one in the project you can snatch.

Comment: Tried using 'pipe:1' instead of just '-' to output to stdout, however I still get the same error. Seems to only be a problem with segmenting though, as outputting a whole file using 'pipe:1' works fine. Thanks anyway.